# How can jquery object use index to access DOM like array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I knew that `jQuery` function `$("selector")` returns an object.

```
var divTest = $(".test"); // returns object
Array.isArray(divTest); // false
typeof divTest; // "object"
```

Using this object wrapped by the `jQuery` function, we can use the API of `jQuery`.

The point that I cannot understand is how we can access native DOM element(s) using an index in `jQuery` objects like we do in arrays.

```
<div class="test first"></div>
<div class="test second"></div>
<div class="test third"></div>

//...
var divTest = $(".test");
console.log(divTest[0]); // <div class="test first"></div>
console.log(divTest[1]); // <div class="test second"></div>
console.log(divTest[2]); // <div class="test third"></div>
```

I opened the uncompressed `jQuery` source file. I think this question is related with the following method.

The method `jQuery.fn.init` returns `jQuery.makeArray(selector, this)`. `makeArray` is extended from `jQuery`.

Can someone give comments to help me understand this issue?

Comment: Issue? That's standard behavior of any jQuery object and other array-like objects. While both true arrays and array-like objects (pseudo-array?) have an index and length that's where the similarities end. The fact that jQuery has methods like `makeArray()` is evidence that the common jQuery Object isn't an array (otherwise why would `makeArray()` exist in the first place)

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146179/how-can-jquery-object-use-index-to-access-dom-like-array/48146261#48146261) for a thorough explanation @YounghunJung.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no issue. The object `$(".test")` returns is array-like *(behaves like an array)*, so you can access the elements it contains the same way as you would if you were using the native function `document.querySelectorAll(".test")`.

There is nothing special to it. What `jQuery` does is use native functions to get the elements and then inject each one to its array-like object. Check out the example below to see how a simple `jQuery-like` function can be made.

**Example:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */

function $ (selector) {
  /* Check whether the context is a $ instance. */
  if (this instanceof $) {
    /* Get the elements matching the given selector. */
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    /* Set the length property of the object. */
    this.length = 0;

    /* Iterate over every element gotten. */
    for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i< l; i++) {
      /* Inject each element in the object. */
      this[i] = elements[i];

      /* Increment the length. */
      this.length++;
    }

    /* Cache the selector as a public property of the object. */
    this.selector = selector;
  }
  else return new $(selector);
}


/* --- Use --- */

var elements = $(".test");
console.log(typeof elements);
console.log(elements[0]);
console.log(elements[1]);
console.log(elements[2]);
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div id = "e1" class = "test"></div>
<div id = "e2" class = "test"></div>
<div id = "e3" class = "test"></div>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Trying to learn `JavaScript` by reading the `jQuery` source code is a bad idea.
2. In order for an object to be *array-like*, it must have:

   - numeric properties *(indices)*,
   - a numeric `length` property and
   - a `splice` method *(optional, to be logged as an array in the console)*.

Comment: Is it possible to make any object array-like?

Comment: Yes. In order for an object to be _array-like_, it must have numeric properties and a `length`. In order to be logged as an array in the console as well, it must also have a `splice` method @mdatsev.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I do not learn JS by reading the jQuery..
The point is that I haven't understood Array-like object.
Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: You're welcome @YounghunJung. I'm glad I could help. I hope it's clear to you what an array-like object is now :)